# Контролируемая анимация WPF

Tags: wpf, анимация

Есть `CustomControl`. в нем находится обьект `Path`, с анимацией.

```
<Path x:Name="vectorGeometryPath" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Fill="#FF95B4D4" Data="F1M22.5863," >
    <Path.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform x:Name="AnimatedRotateTransform" Angle="0"  />
    </Path.RenderTransform>
    <Path.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="local:AnimControl.AnimActive">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="AnimatedRotateTransform"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle" 
                            To="360" Duration="0:0:1" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Path.Triggers>
</Path>
```

Хочу сделать так, что бы при изменении свойства `AnimStart`, анимация включалась и выключалась, но не понимаю по какому принципу такое реализуется. 
Вот код для `UserControl`:

```
public partial class AnimControl : UserControl
{
    public static readonly RoutedEvent AnimActiveEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("AnimActive", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(Rotate360Loading));

    public event RoutedEventHandler AnimActive
    {
        add{ this.AddHandler(AnimActiveEvent, value); }
        remove { this.RemoveHandler(AnimActiveEvent, value); }
    }

    public AnimControl ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty AnimStartProperty =
  DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(AnimStart), typeof(bool), typeof(Rotate360Loading), new PropertyMetadata(false));

    public bool AnimStart
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(AnimStartProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AnimStartProperty, value); }
    }

    public void RaiseMyEvent()
    {
        RoutedEventArgs newEventArgs = new RoutedEventArgs(AnimActiveEvent);
        vectorGeometryPath.RaiseEvent(newEventArgs);
    }
}
```

Вот и вопрос: как управлять началом и остановкой анимации? Желательно через код.

Comment: У Вас, в примере разметки вижу свойство:  RepeatBehavior="Forever".
Наверняка там возможны другие варианты, более соответствующие Вашему заданию

Comment: @ale , нет, `RepeatBehavior="Forever"` это как раз то, что нужно.

Comment: Можно вынести Storyboard в ресурсы и использовать [StopStoryboard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.stopstoryboard%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) для остановки (по аналогии с BeginStoryboard, в обоих указывая один и тот же Storyboard).